# In Kops v 1.16, Getting Status NeedsUpdate and Ready 0 in "kops rolling-update cluster" in aws spot instance group though cluster is running good

Tags: kubernetes

I am getting Status **NeedsUpdate**  and **Ready**  0 in response of command `kops rolling-update cluster` in aws  spot instance group though all are running fine. I have run `kops rolling-update cluster --yes`  for several times and got successfully completed rolling update. But still, Getting NeedsUpdate status. How can I solve this issue?

```
kops rolling-update cluster

NAME                    STATUS          NEEDUPDATE      READY   MIN     MAX     NODES
master-ap-south-1       Ready           0               1       1       1       1
nodes                   Ready           0               0       0       5       0
nodes-spot              NeedsUpdate     2               0       2       7       2
```

Comment: Can you check with updating only `nodes-spot` isntance group by running `kops rolling-update cluster <cluster-name> --yes   --fail-on-validate-error="false" --node-interval 8m --instance-group nodes-spot` ?

Comment: ok i am checking now.

Comment: @hoque no its not solved the problem.

Comment: what is your kops version?

Comment: kops Version 1.16.0

Comment: can you check https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/7142#issuecomment-605100817 and try with kops 1.18.0-alpha.2 version?

Comment: @hoque, thanks for this answer, i  have read the given thread and found this issue is solved in the 1.18.0-alpha.2 version. I will try that version.

Comment: This issue has been solved in kops version 1.16.3 which released just 7 days ago.

Comment: did update fix the problem?

Comment: yes, i just updated  kops from  1.16.0 to 1.16.3 and got solved.

Comment: ok I am adding my comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From kops issues tab I see there is some issue with sport instance.

According to [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/7142#issuecomment-605100817)

> This issue is fixed in 1.18 and should be testable with Kops 1.18.0-alpha.2.

Comment: This issue is also fixed in kops version 1.16.3.